# How do I lowercase a string in C?

Tags: c, string, lowercase

How can I convert a mixed case string to a lowercase string in C?

Comment: Are you just dealing with ASCII with letters a-z only?

Comment: ascii. how would i take that into account? would the example below still work? what happens if my char is a '#' and tolower() gets called on it?

Comment: That will work. I was more thinking if your string contains things like é or Ü.

Comment: Why not just use "strlwr"? `strlwr((char*)str);` It just goes through the string and converts it itself.

Comment: @Larry It's non-standard.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

It's in the standard library, and that's the most straight forward way I can see to implement such a function. So yes, just loop through the string and convert each character to lowercase.

Something trivial like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
  str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}
```

or if you prefer one liners, then you can use this one by J.F. Sebastian:

```
for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
```

Comment: `for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);` seems more idiomatic.

Comment: @J.F. there you go. Depends on if they want the code to look scary or nice :) (very readable one liner, but it does look scary)

Comment: this gives me a segfault if str is a `char *`, but not if str is a char array. Got any explanation for that?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I guess if you used `char *` you used really a string constant which gets placed in unwriteable memory section. So if you try to change the value of that it gives you a segfault. If, on the other hand, you would copy that constant string to a `char *copy = strdup (const_string)` then `copy` could be altered because it is allocated on the heap, which is writeable. So all in all it does not have anything to do with using a pointer (`char *`) but with using constant strings like in code: `char *const_str = "my const string"`.

Comment: I believe the one liner will cause you to lose your pointer to the string.

Comment: I believe that one liner will have untold ramifications.

Comment: the one-liner results in `error: lvalue required as increment operand`

Comment: @jfs Why not `while (*p = tolower(*p)) ++p;` or `while (*p = tolower(*p++))` for the purpose of obfuscation (the latter only works since C++17) ;-)

Comment: The last character in the c string represented by **p** is the character ``'\0'`` numericaly represented as literal ``0``. So when it encounters the last character as it increments, the loop terminates since it is falsy. I believe there are no ramifications [NOP da CALL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5352244/nop-da-call).

Comment: You forgot to convert the (possibly signed) `char` value before passing to `tolower()` (which requires _positive_ versions of characters, or `EOF`).

Answer (score 9):

to convert to lower case is equivalent to rise bit 0x60 if you restrict yourself to ASCII:

```
for(char *p = pstr; *p; ++p)
    *p = *p > 0x40 && *p < 0x5b ? *p | 0x60 : *p;
```

Comment: To make it slightly more readable you could do `for(char *p = pstr;*p;++p) *p=*p>='A'&&*p<='Z'?*p|0x60:*p;`

Comment: This version is actually slower than glibc's `tolower()`. 55.2 vs. 44.15 on my machine.

Comment: i can't imagine that: tolower() deals with chars; only if it's macro

Comment: @oraz: tolower() has `int (*)(int)` signature. Here's the code used for performance measurements http://gist.github.com/370497

Comment: @J.F.: i see, they've used table, but i can optimize: for ( ; *p; ++p) if(*p > 'Z') {continue;} else if (*p < 'A') {continue;} else {*p = *p|0x60;}

Comment: @oraz: `if (*p > 'Z')` optimization performs better on the input I've used, but if there are many upper-case letters it takes the same time as the previous version.

Comment: The fastest version uses a lookup table instead of branches.

Comment: Note that this is an ASCII-only conversion that is not strictly conforming C.  C provides no guarantees that upper- (or lower-)case letter are represented consecutively in any character set.

Answer (score 7):

Looping the pointer to gain better performance:

```c
#include <ctype.h>

char* toLower(char* s) {
  for(char *p=s; *p; p++) *p=tolower(*p);
  return s;
}
char* toUpper(char* s) {
  for(char *p=s; *p; p++) *p=toupper(*p);
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Well if you're going the one-liner way, then `s` is a local variable in your function, you can directly use it instead of declaring `p`.`

Comment: @NewbiZ, indeed:
    // convert string to lowercase, in place:
    char* toLower(char* p) {
      for( ; *p; p++) *p=tolower(*p);
      return p;
    }

Comment: @NewbiZ, not given this signature (which returns pointer to the start of string).  A copy needs to be made somewhere!

Comment: @TobySpeight, oh right indeed

Answer (score 1):

If we're going to be as sloppy as to use `tolower()`, do this:

```
char blah[] = "blah blah Blah BLAH blAH\0";
int i = 0;
while( blah[i] |=' ', blah[++i] ) {}
```

But, well, it kinda explodes if you feed it some symbols/numerals, and in general it's evil.  Good interview question, though.

Comment: Yeah, this will fold/spindle/mutilate a variety of symbols (in ASCII, any symbol, control character, or numeral with bit 5 clear will become the same character code with bit 5 set, etc) so really, seriously, don't use it.

Comment: This post is discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270402/is-ghetto-an-offensive-word).

Comment: Can you elaborate more? When I read about tolower(), they all mention that they only work on characters that have a lowercase character defined for them. From opengroup.org: "If the argument of tolower() represents an uppercase letter, and there exists a corresponding lowercase letter [CX] [Option Start]  (as defined by character type information in the program locale category LC_CTYPE ), [Option End] the result shall be the corresponding lowercase letter. All other arguments in the domain are returned unchanged." If this is the case, where does tolower() fail?

Answer (score -2):

I'm new to C and have been trying hard to convert strings from uppercase to lowercase. I made the mistake of changing the string 'A' + 32 = 'a'. And I can't solve the problem.

I used char type and finally I was able to convert it to string type. You can consult:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string convert_lower(string str)
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    char c[length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] <= 'Z' || str[i] >= 'A')
        {
            c[i] = tolower((char)str[i]);
        }
    }
    c[length] = '\0';
    string text = c;
    return text;
}
```