# How to set a string to all lowercase

Tags: c, uppercase, lowercase, tolower, toupper

I have a `char foo[SIZE]; //(string)`

and have inputed it correctly using `%s` (as in it `printfs` the correct input), but now want to set it to lowercase. So I tried using

```
 if (isupper(*foo)) 
   *foo=tolower(*foo);
```

ie when I do:

```
printf("%s" foo); //I get the same text with upper case
```

The text does not seem to change. Thank you.

Comment: You can use [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) to remove the non-alpha characters.

Comment: `isupper` and `tolower` applies only to a single char, not string.

Comment: @Yu Hao so there is no way to apply it to string?

Comment: You need to use `for` to iterate through every char of the string, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/c-convert-a-mixed-case-string-to-all-lower-case

Answer (score 5):

`foo` isn't a pointer, so you don't want to use it as one. You also don't have to check whether a character is an upper-case letter before using `tolower` -- it converts upper to lower case, and leaves other characters unchanged. You probably want something like:

```
for (i=0; foo[i]; i++)
    foo[i] = tolower((unsigned char)foo[i]);
```

Note that when you call `tolower` (and `toupper`, `isalpha`, etc.) you really need to cast your input to `unsigned char`. Otherwise, many (most?) characters outside the basic English/ASCII character set will frequently lead to undefined behavior (e.g., in a typical case, most accented characters will show up as negative numbers).

As an aside, when you're reading the string, you don't want to use `scanf` with `%s` -- you always want to specify the string length, something like: `scanf("%19s", foo);`, assuming `SIZE` == 20 (i.e., you want to specify one less than the size. Alternatively, you could use `fgets`, like `fgets(foo, 20, infile);`. Note that with `fgets`, you specify the size of the buffer, not one less like you do with `scanf` (and company like fscanf).

Comment: +1 for the "`aside....`" part

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for(i = 0; foo[i]; i++){
  foo[i] = tolower(foo[i]);
}
```

Comment: what does the foo[i] in the middle of the for loop mean? is that like i<foo?

Comment: @user2450044 your char array is/should be null terminated...and then that `foo[i]` is evaluated to `false` when the end of the array is reached.

Comment: @user2450044 You can use `foo[i] != '\0'`, but NOT `i <'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

`*foo=tolower(*foo); //doing *(foo+i) or foo[i] does not work either`

because all of those options do not make sense

You should use it like this:

```
for(i = 0; foo[i] != '\0'; i++){
    foo[i] = tolower(foo[i]);
}
```

Comment: what does the foo[i] in the middle mean?

Comment: NULL or `\0`?? I think `\0` is better since it is a char array.

Comment: ok, now +1 for the answer :)

Comment: @user2450044 **ever** read about for loops in C? Make some effort man, seriously...