# Palindrome finder in C?

Tags: c, palindrome

I'm trying to make a palindrome finder in C and I don't know where it is going wrong, no matter what I get the output false on the 2 different ways that I have tried to code this. I have only just started C (in the past week) so if you could explain things simply that'd be great, thanks!

```
//way1
#include <stdio.h>

int read_char() { return getchar(); }
void read_string(char* s, int size) { fgets(s, size, stdin); }

void print_char(int c)     { putchar(c); }   
void print_string(char* s) { printf("%s", s); }


int is_palin(char word[]) {

  int m = 0;
  int arr_len = sizeof(word) / sizeof(char); //change to char_index
  int n = arr_len;
  int t = 1;

  if(n % 2 != 0) {
    for (m=0; m < ((n-1)/2); m++) {
      if(word[m] != word[n-m-2]) {
        t = 0;
      }
      else {
        t = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for (m=0; m < (n/2)-1; m++) {
      if(word[m] != word[n-m-2]) {
        t = 0;
      }
      else {
        t = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  if(t == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char word[6] = "civic";
  int arr_len = sizeof(word)/sizeof(char);

  if (is_palin(word) == 1) {
    printf("is palin\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("is not palin\n");
  }

  printf(word);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d\n", arr_len);
  return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//way2
#include <stdio.h>

int read_char() { return getchar(); }
void read_string(char* s, int size) { fgets(s, size, stdin); }

void print_char(int c)     { putchar(c); }   
void print_string(char* s) { printf("%s", s); }


int is_palin(char word[]) {
  int m = 1;
  int input_length = sizeof(word);
  int j = input_length-1;
  int i = 0;

  for(i=0; i <= j; i++) {
    if(word[i] != word[j]) {
      m = 0;
      j--;
    }
  }

  if(m == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}


int main(void) {
  char word[6] = "civic";
  int input_length = sizeof(word);

  if (is_palin(word) == 1) {
    printf("is palin\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("is not palin\n");
  }

  printf(word);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d\n", input_length);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof word` does not result in what you expect. You actually need strlen() here.

Comment: ..something you would have found  yourself, very quickly, if you had used a debugger.  'I have only just started C (in the past week)' OK, but you need to learn how to debug NOW before you write any more code.

Comment: ... but putting a few printf() statements at strategic points can be just as effective as *using a debugger*. BTW: fgets() reads the input *including the final '\n'* You probably want to remove that first, before trying to find (no) palindromes.

Comment: I would advice you that this is not a good idea to declare function like that. Before main you should only write prototypes of functions, after main you actually have to declare the function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works fine.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main(  )
    {
      int flag = 0;
      int length = 0;
      int len2 = 0;
      int i = 0;
      char name[130];
      char p[130];
      char q[130];

      printf( "please enter a name or sentence\n" );
      scanf( "%[^\n]", name );

      length = strlen( name );
      len2 = length;
      strcpy( p, name );
      memset( q, '.', length ); // handy to debug comparaison
      q[length] = '\0';

      for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
      {
        q[--len2] = p[i];
      }

      printf( "\n p==%s", p );
      printf( "\n q==%s", q );
      getchar(  );

      if ( !strcmp( p, q ) )
        flag = 1;

      if ( flag == 1 )
        printf( "\npalindrome\n" );
      else
        printf( "\nnot a palindrome\n" );

      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, that's how I have implemented it (remember to `#include <stdbool.h>` or it will not work):

```
for(i = 0; i < string_length; i++)
    {
            if(sentence[i] == sentence[string_lenght-1-i])
                    palindrome = true;
            else
            {
                    palindrome = false;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Doing that it will check if your sentence is palindrome and, at the first occurence this is not true it will break the for loop. You can use something like

```
if(palindrome)
     printf(..);
else
     printf(..);
```

for a simple prompt for the user.

Example :

> radar is palindrome
>
> abba is palindrome
>
> abcabc is not palindrome

Please , pay attention to the fact that

> Abba

is not recognized as a palindrome due to the fact that ' A ' and 'a' have different ASCII codes :

> 'A' has the value of 65
>
> 'a' has the value of 97
>   according to the [ASCII table](http://web.alfredstate.edu/weimandn/miscellaneous/ascii/ASCII%20Conversion%20Chart.gif). You can find out more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

You can avoid this issue trasforming all the characters of the string to lower case characters.
You can do this including the `<ctype.h>` library and calling the function `int tolower(int c);` like that :

> ```
> for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
>   str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
> }
> ```
>
> Code by [Earlz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69742/earlz), take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/c-convert-a-mixed-case-string-to-all-lower-case) to look deeper into that.

EDIT : I made a simple program to do this, see if it can help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void LowerCharacters(char *word, int word_lenth);

int main(void){

    char *word = (char *) malloc(10);
    bool palindrome = false;

    if(word == 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR : Out of memory.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter a word to check if it is palindrome or not : ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    int word_length = strlen(word);

    LowerCharacters(word,word_length);

    for(int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == word[word_length-1-i])
            palindrome = true;
        else
        {
            palindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    palindrome ? printf("\nThe word %s is palindrome.\n\n", word) : printf("\nThe word %s is not palindrome.\n\n", word);

    free(word);

return 0;

}

void LowerCharacters(char *word, int word_length){

    for(int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
}
```

Input :

> Enter a word to check if it is palindrome or not : RadaR

Output :

> The word radar is palindrome.