# Check whether string is palindrome

Tags: c, string

I am writing some code to check whether a string is a palindrome, but it's giving me a runtime error. I can't spot where the error is. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char a[20];
  int n,c;
  c=0;
  printf("enter the size of the string  ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("enter the string ");
  fgets(a,n,stdin);

  for(int i=0;i<(n-1)/2;i++)
  {
      if(a[i]==a[n-1-i])
      {
          c=0;
      }
      else
      {
          c=1;
          break;
      }
  }

  if(c==0)
      printf("string is palindrome");
  else
      printf("string is not palindrome");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Palindrome program in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784096/palindrome-program-in-c)

Comment: It's more useful to specify *what* runtime error you get ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing I notice, upon compiling and executing this, is
that it doesn’t let you enter the string. This is due to the way you’re
taking input:

```
printf("enter the size of the string  ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("enter the string ");
fgets(a,n,stdin);
```

It runs `scanf("%d",&n);`. So the user types, say, `6`, followed by the
enter key. Hokay, so `scanf` looks at those characters `6\n`, takes the
`6`, converts to a number, and `n` ends up with a value of 6.

But that newline is still there. `scanf` didn’t do anything with it
because it’s not numeric. So, when the code gets to here:

```
fgets(a,n,stdin);
```

It then reads that newline and thinks “Okay! The user entered an empty
string.” (Yes I know I’m being anthropomorphic, sue me.)

This sort of behavior is why I avoid using `scanf`. I would code it this
way:

```
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
n = atoi(a);
printf("enter the string ");
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
```

Note that this also limits each `fgets` to the size of the buffer,
avoiding potential buffer overflows. This is an important consideration
with working code, because a buffer overflow can easily lead to a
vulnerability that can be exploited to break security. Best to develop
good habits even with simple learning programs like this.

Note also that a better way to do this would be to simply read the
string by itself, then compute its length with `strlen`.

At this point, it seems to be working correctly, so I won’t delve into
the rest of it. However, if you take my advice about computing the
length, there’s one more thing to be aware of. If you add this line
(temporarily, just for debugging purposes):

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(a));
```

You will see that you have one more character than you expect. That is
because `fgets` retains the newline. So, we want to get rid of it:

```
a[strlen(a) - 1] = '\0';
```

This isn’t necessary if you use the value of `n`, because then it will
just ignore the newline and use the `n` characters preceding it. But it
would be necessary if you’re computing the length.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, that's how I have implemented it (remember to `#include <stdbool.h>` or it will not work):

```
for(i = 0; i < string_length; i++)
    {
            if(sentence[i] == sentence[string_lenght-1-i])
                    palindrome = true;
            else
            {
                    palindrome = false;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Doing that it will check if your sentence is palindrome and, at the first occurence this is not true it will break the for loop. You can use something like

```
if(palindrome)
     printf(..);
else
     printf(..);
```

for a simple prompt for the user.

Example :

> radar is palindrome
>
> abba is palindrome
>
> abcabc is not palindrome

Please , pay attention to the fact that

> Abba

is not recognized as a palindrome due to the fact that ' A ' and 'a' have different ASCII codes :

> 'A' has the value of 65
>
> 'a' has the value of 97
>   according to the [ASCII table](http://web.alfredstate.edu/weimandn/miscellaneous/ascii/ASCII%20Conversion%20Chart.gif). You can find out more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

You can avoid this issue trasforming all the characters of the string to lower case characters.
You can do this including the `<ctype.h>` library and calling the function `int tolower(int c);` like that :

> ```
> for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
>   str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
> }
> ```
>
> Code by [Earlz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69742/earlz), take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/c-convert-a-mixed-case-string-to-all-lower-case) to look deeper into that.

EDIT : I made a simple program (however it's a sample, it can be further optimised and so on, it's just to give you the idea), see if it can help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void LowerCharacters(char *word, int word_lenth);

int main(void){

    char *word = (char *) malloc(10);
    bool palindrome = false;

    if(word == 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR : Out of memory.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter a word to check if it is palindrome or not : ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    int word_length = strlen(word);

    LowerCharacters(word,word_length);

    for(int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == word[word_length-1-i])
            palindrome = true;
        else
        {
            palindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    palindrome ? printf("\nThe word %s is palindrome.\n\n", word) : printf("\nThe word %s is not palindrome.\n\n", word);

    free(word);

return 0;

}

void LowerCharacters(char *word, int word_length){

    for(int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
}
```

Input :

> Enter a word to check if it is palindrome or not : RadaR

Output :

> The word radar is palindrome.