# Palindrome program in C

Tags: c, palindrome

My program in C which is Palindrome has an error in its function. My function is not comparing the 2 characters in my string. When I type a single character it answers palindrome but if it is two or more always not palindrome.

Code:

```
          int IntStrlength=strlen(StrWord);
          int IntCtr2=0;
          int IntCtr=1, IntAnswer;
          while(IntCtr<=(IntStrlength/2)){
                printf(" %d %d\n", IntCtr2,IntStrlength);
               if(StrWord[IntStrlength] != StrWord[IntCtr2]){
                  IntAnswer=0;
                  printf(" %d=Not Palindrome", IntAnswer);
                  exit (0);
                 }//if(StrWord[IntCtr2]!=StrWord[IntStrlength]) <---------
               else{
                  IntCtr2++;
                  IntStrlength--;
                  }// else <--------
               IntCtr++;
          }//while(IntCtr<IntStrlength/2) <-----------
          IntAnswer=1;
          printf(" %d=Palindrome", IntAnswer);
          return ;
```

}

Single character:

[image]

Two or more characters:

[image]

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I cant still find the problem

Comment: You're not showing us nearly enough code. What's `IntCtr2`?! To what are `IntCtr` and `IntStrlength` initialised?

Comment: Sorry , and advance thank you

Comment: your counters are messed up. for example you always take `StrWord[IntStrlength]`. And you should use only one counter. And your counter should start at index 0...

Comment: `StrWord[IntStrLength]` is the terminating null character in the first iteration. The use of `IntCtr` and `IntCtr2` is very confusing; perhaps you need just one variable here? And your program flow is strange. When the word is a palindrome you exit? That's really quick and dirty. Make the palindrome check into a function and treturn 0 or 1 accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write it like this

```
int wordLength = strlen(StrWord);
for (int i=0;i<(wordLength/2);i++) {
    if (StrWord[i] != StrWord[wordLength-i-1]) {
        return 0;
    }
}

return 1;
```

For words with an even length (say 8) the counter will go from 0 to 3, accessing all letters. For uneven words (say 7) the c ounter will go from 0 to 2, leaving the middle element unchecked. This is not necessary since its a palindrome and it always matches itself

Comment: The first time you execute the wile loop this check is done:
if(StrWord[IntStrlength] != StrWord[IntCtr2])

IntStrlength is 1 based, not 0. so this will get the terminating character of the string, and compare it to the first letter. this check will always fail. you must use IntStrlength-1

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int check_palindrom(char *);
int main()
{
        char s1[20];
        printf("Enter the string...\n");
        gets(s1);

        int x;
        x=check_palindrom(s1);
        x?printf("Palindrom\n"):printf("Not Palindrom\n");
}
int check_palindrom(char *s)
{
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;s[i];i++);

        for(i=i-1,j=0;i>j;i--,j++)
                if(s[i]!=s[j])
                        return 0;
        if(s[i]==s[j])
                return 1;
}
```

> Enter the string...
>
> radar
>
> Palindrom

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this algorithm before in a interview book called "Cracking the Coding Interview".

In it the author shows a very simple and easy implementation of the code. The code is below: Also [here](https://youtu.be/WFzg1PeniFY) is a video explaining the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> // strlen()

void isPalindrome(char str[]);

int main(){

    isPalindrome("MOM");
    isPalindrome("M");
    return 0;
}




void isPalindrome(char str[]){

    int lm = 0;//left most index
    int rm = strlen(str) - 1;//right most index

    while(rm > lm){

        if(str[lm++] != str[rm--]){

            printf("No, %s is NOT a palindrome \n", str);
            return;
        }

    }

    printf("Yes, %s is a palindrome because the word reversed is the same \n", str);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, that's how I have implemented it (remember to `#include <stdbool.h>` or it will not work):

```
for(i = 0; i < string_length; i++)
    {
            if(sentence[i] == sentence[string_lenght-1-i])
                    palindrome = true;
            else
            {
                    palindrome = false;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Doing that it will check if your sentence is palindrome and, at the first occurence this is not true it will break the for loop. You can use something like

```
if(palindrome)
     printf(..);
else
     printf(..);
```

for a simple prompt for the user.

Example :

> radar is palindrome
>
> abba is palindrome
>
> abcabc is not palindrome

Please , pay attention to the fact that

> Abba

is not recognized as a palindrome due to the fact that ' A ' and 'a' have different ASCII codes :

> 'A' has the value of 65
>
> 'a' has the value of 97
>   according to the [ASCII table](http://web.alfredstate.edu/weimandn/miscellaneous/ascii/ASCII%20Conversion%20Chart.gif). You can find out more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

You can avoid this issue trasforming all the characters of the string to lower case characters.
You can do this including the `<ctype.h>` library and calling the function `int tolower(int c);` like that :

> ```
> for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
>   str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
> }
> ```
>
> Code by [Earlz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69742/earlz), take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/c-convert-a-mixed-case-string-to-all-lower-case) to look deeper into that.

EDIT : I made a simple program to do this, see if it can help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void LowerCharacters(char *word, int word_lenth);

int main(void){

    char *word = (char *) malloc(10);
    bool palindrome = false;

    if(word == 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR : Out of memory.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter a word to check if it is palindrome or not : ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    int word_length = strlen(word);

    LowerCharacters(word,word_length);

    for(int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == word[word_length-1-i])
            palindrome = true;
        else
        {
            palindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    palindrome ? printf("\nThe word %s is palindrome.\n\n", word) : printf("\nThe word %s is not palindrome.\n\n", word);

    free(word);

return 0;

}

void LowerCharacters(char *word, int word_length){

    for(int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
}
```

Input :

> Enter a word to check if it is palindrome or not : RadaR

Output :

> The word radar is palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_palindrome(char string []);
int main()
{
        char string[20];
        printf("Enter the string...\n");
        scanf ("%s", &string);

        int check;
        check = check_palindrome (string);
        if (check == 0)
            printf ("Not Palindrome\n");
        else
            printf ("Palindrome\n");
        return 0;
}
int check_palindrome (char string [])
{
        char duplicate [];
        strcpy (string, duplicate);
        strrev (string);
        if (strcmp (string, duplicate) == 0)
           return 1;
        else
           return 0;
}
```

This uses the `strcmp` and `strrev` function.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you to understand the concept:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char str[50];
 int i,j,flag=1;
 printf("Enter the string");
 gets(str);
 for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++);
 for(i=i-1,j=0;j<i;j++,i--)
 {
    str[i]=str[i]+str[j];
    str[j]=str[i]-str[j];
    str[i]=str[i]-str[j];
 }
 for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++);
 for(i=i-1,j=0;j<i;j++,i--)
 {
    if(str[i]==str[j]){
        flag=0;
        break;
    }
 }if(flag==0)
 {
    printf("Palindrome");
 }else
 { 
    printf("Not Palindrome");
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solution for this    
char a[]="abbba";
int i,j,b=strlen(a),flag=0;
          for(i=0,j=0; i<b; i++,j++)
          {
              if(a[i]!=a[b-j-1])
              {
               flag=1;
               break;
              } 
          }
        if(flag)
        {

                      printf("the string is not palindrum");
        }
        else
              {
                      printf("the string is  palindrum");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This may works for you

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main(void) {
        setbuf(stdout,NULL);
        int i,limit;
        char string1[10];
        int flag=0;
    
    
        printf("enter a string");
        scanf("%s",string1);
        limit=strlen(string1);
        for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
            if(string1[i]!=string1[limit-i-1]){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
    
        }   if(flag==1){
            printf("entered string is not  palindrome");
        }else{
            printf("entered string is  palindrome");
        }
    
    
    
    
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```