# Problem in a program to convert upper case string to lowercase using function in C

Tags: c, string, function

I am trying to write a program which will only compare same case letter, but first it should convert any case to a particular case.

But I am having trouble converting the string to any particular case using a function, though I have figured out how to do that without a function. Here's my code.  Can anyone help me find out where I am going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void order(char input[])
{
    int i=0;

    while(input[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(input[i]>'65' && input[i]<'92')
        {
            input[i]+=32;
           // printf("WORKING\n");
        }

        i++;

    }
}
int main()
{
    char input1[101], output1[101];
    char input2[101], output2[101];
    int r;

    scanf("%s",tolower(input1));
    scanf("%s",input2);

    order(input1);
    order(input2);

    printf("%s\n",input1);
    printf("%s\n",input2);

    /*

    r=strcmp(output1,output2);


    if(r<0)
        printf("-1\n");
    else if(r>0)
        printf("1\n");
    else
        printf("0\n");

    */

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(input[i]>'65' && input[i]<'92')
```

to this:

```
if(input[i] >= 65 && input[i] <= 90)
```

since you want to check for the ASCII codes of A and Z. Notice that because you used magic numbers, you made a mistake for both. I had to check an ASCII table to figure that out that you needed the equality sign as well, and 90 (code for Z), instead of 92 (code for '\').

I suggest you then to use characters constants, like this:

```
if(input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')
```

Comment: output is showing same string like the inserted one

Comment: Yes @mahinhossen I understand that. I am asking what would *you* like the function to do a given string. For example, if I give "FOO" to your function, what would you like the output to be?

Comment: first of all sorry for editing the question,i will edit now it to original one.And secondly there will be two sting input,so i want both string to be changed permanently in same case.

Comment: i want it to convert string to any particular case,either uppercase or lowercase

Comment: i want the function to convert in any case,as given example i want it to convert it to lowercase,got the answer,thanks though.My syntax was wrong

Comment: Not only clearer to use the character constants, but now also more portable.  Everyone's a winner!

Comment: @TobySpeight The "more portable" gets into deeper issues.  1) Aside from ubiquitous ASCII, using `'A'` with EBCDIC, does not help as [A-Z] is not continuous, so the `if()` is broken code.  2) The character encoding of source code and encoding file characters may differ.  Still for learners, `'A'` vs `65` is best.

Comment: `+=32` isn't portable either. It's much more straightforward to have an explicit mapping table for a particular character encoding and culture. And, if the character encoding can be (or be compatible with) the execution-charset, literals can be used. It's unfortunate that text-domain exercises are used to teach syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Constant and off-by-1 errors.

- `'65'` is a multi byte constant and certainly `65` was meant.  [@gsamaras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411320/gsamaras).  ASCII `Z` is 90.

  ```
  // if(input[i]>'65' && input[i]<'92')
  if(input[i]>65 && input[i]< Zee)
  ```
- Off by 1 due to `>` vs. `>=`

  ```
  // if(input[i]>'65' && input[i]<'92')
  // if(input[i]>65 && input[i]< Zee)
  if(input[i] >= 65 && input[i] <= 90)
  ```

---

Character constants are more self documenting.  Consider `'A'`

```
    if(input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')
```

Ideally code would use standard C library functions to detect case.

```
    if(isupper((unsigned char) input[i]))
```

Yet code could call `toupper()` directly and skip the `if()`.

```
while(input[i]) {
  input[i] = tolower((unsigned char) input[i]);
  i++;
}

// or 

for (size_t i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
  input[i] = tolower((unsigned char) input[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a `char*` to the `tolower` in `scanf("%s",tolower(input1));`.

Change it to `scanf("%s", input1);`

[c - convert a mixed-case string to all lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/c-convert-a-mixed-case-string-to-all-lower-case) should tell you how to convert a string to lower case.

Take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower and https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper.

Comment: sorry,was trying to do that so that it can take string as lowercase,but it didn't work.forgot to change it while posting here