# String operations cause segfault C

Tags: arrays, c, char

I'm trying to 'deep copy' a string so that I can perform operations on one copy, while retaining the original copy. This is the base example that I've got and for some reason the strncpy call causes a segfault. Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* stringA = "someVeryinTeresTingString";
    char* stringB = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stringA));
    
    printf("A: %s, B: %s\n", stringA, stringB);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stringA); i++) {
        stringB[i] = tolower(stringA[i]);
    }
    
    printf("A: %s, B: %s\n", stringA, stringB);
    
    strncpy(stringA, stringB, strlen(stringA) - 1);
    
    printf("A: %s, B: %s\n", stringA, stringB);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Don't forget the NUL terminator. Don't forget `strdup()` if you have it.

Comment: `malloc()` may return junk data. `stringB` is not a valid C string until you clear it or put something in it.

Comment: `stringA` is also not mutable, it's a static string and should be considered to be `const char*`. You need a buffer you can write to, so allocate a new one, or as mentioned, just use `strdup()`.

Comment: @tadman so if I wanted to write a method to return the lowercase of a string, I'd have to create a new char*, dump the contents into that, free the pointer passed in and return the new char* pointer?

Comment: Yeah. Inline string literals are special in that they're not stored in mutable memory, they're effectively immutable. You need to copy them, so you can do `char stringA[] = "..."` which creates a local array, not a pointer, or you can `strdup()` to create a copy.

Comment: @M.Choy Yes, that is one way to do it.

Comment: @tadman, but in this SO post here, they are editing the ith index of a string, which implies that string are somewhat immutable?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-c

Comment: C strings on the stack or heap *are* mutable. [*C string literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) are not.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see your post below :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest fix is to make a local copy of that string literal:

```c
char stringA[] = "someVeryinTeresTingString";
```

Everything else works just the same.

Note that in the original code you have a pointer to immutable memory, while in this version you have a local (stack) array that is initialized with a copy of that string.

Another thing to note is if you're copying and manipulating C strings, do things like this:

```c
char* stringB = strdup(stringA);
  
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stringB); ++i) {
    stringB[i] = tolower(stringB[i]);
}
```

Or even more efficiently by avoiding all these expensive `strlen()` calls:

```c
char* stringB = strdup(stringA);
  
for (char* p = stringB; *p; ++p) {
    *p = tolower(*p);
}
```

Comment: Hmm `printf("B: %s\n", stringB);` remains UB as `stringB` is not a _string_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I mentioned that in a comment. It's not touched on here.

Comment: All 3  `printf("B: %s\n", stringB);` are UB as `stringB` lacks a null character or space for it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm recommending `strdup()` here in place of the original code. That solves that issue.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: Please note that `strdup` is not C standard and non-portable. Though I heard some rumour about adding it to C2x.

Comment: @Lundin Some things in POSIX were admittedly a mistake, like `gets()`, but I'm not sure `stdrup()` is one of them.

Comment: anyway, if `strdup` is missing in your setup, coding it is pretty trivial. Everywhere else (99.9% of the time) it exists.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
char* stringB = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stringA));
```

shuld be like this:

```
char* stringB = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(stringA) + 1));
```

then you will able to copy the \0 in the end of stringA

**also, you want to copy to literal string - that is segmentation fault**

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

Comment: Why can't I copy a string literal?

Comment: you can copy string literal but you cant copy  t-o string literal. you can switch stringA and stringB in the strncpy function and it will run

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot that strlen(stringA) is the length of stringA without the \0 char

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to comment and correct in your own code the mistakes I've seen:

(I will not correct things that can be eliminated or better done in another way, but are correct or not harmful, so you'll see only what **must be** corrected because of programming errors, and not questions about style or programming uses)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* stringA = "someVeryinTeresTingString";

    /* you need to consider the space for the final null character in the malloc() call */
    char* stringB = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(stringA) + 1));
    /* you don't need to use sizeof(char) as it is always equal to one.
     * Multiplying by one is not necessary, but you'll probably know.
     * char is warranteed by C standard that its sizeof is one. */

    /* you need to copy the string *before* printing, or you will print an 
     * uninitialized string.  Or at least initialize stringB to zeros, so you can
     * use it with printf like functions  (I do initialize the first char position to
     * zero to make it appear as a length zero "" string)
     * You will incurr in undefined behaviour if you don't do this. */
    stringB[0] = '\0';
    
    printf("A: %s, B: %s\n", stringA, stringB);
    
    /* you need to copy the strings, so you can do it better if you test when
     * stringA[i] == '\0', so you don't calculate the length of a string that is
     * not going to change at every loop iteration.  I will not change your
     * code, because this is not an error.  But strlen() searches from the
     * beginning of the string for the '\0' char, character by character,
     * and this test is done at every loop iteration.  With the expression
     * stringA[i] == 0 you do only a test per loop iteration to see if
     * the char at position i in stringA is the null character. */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(stringA); i++) {
        stringB[i] = tolower(stringA[i]);
    }
    /* you have not copied the final '\0', so I do it now.  I need to move the
     * declaration of i outside of the loop to be able to use it's value. */
    stringB[i] = 0;  /* you can use 0 or '\0' interchangeably */
    
    printf("A: %s, B: %s\n", stringA, stringB);
    
    /* nope.  you need to copy the strings with a normal strcpy() as you know that
     * both are the same length  (better, you know that the space in stringB
     * is the same as the length of stringA plus one).  If you do this, you will not copy the last '\0' char, so wee need to append it.
     * well, I don't know if that is what you want, so I don't actually touch anything here. */
    strncpy(stringA, stringB, strlen(stringA) - 1);
    
    /* stringB should be one char shorter than stringA */
    printf("A: %s, B: %s\n", stringA, stringB);
}
```

by the way, you have been recommended to use `strdup(3)`.  This is a good idea, you don't need to be thinking on final nulls in this case, because `strdup()` takes care of it.  Just remember that `strdup(3)` is not included in many C standard revisions, so you can get in trouble if you
move your program to a place lacking it (that should be very strange, anyway)